# Community login page is not translated via language picker

Tags: customer-community, community-builder, login, translation, language

I have an issue on translating the community login page.
I have created a community builder login page and added the language picker component. But when I change the language , login form labels are not translated .
[image]

**But this is working for home page**.

All the labels in the login page are provided by community.

[image]

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. There is a custom loginForm.cmp available. There we have to enable it to use for communities(implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes").
Then we can use this custom form with custom labels in community builder page instead of standard login form.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder attributes have to defined for each Language,
In the Builder, 
Choose a language and add the attributes

[image: Component attributes for English]

For a different language, switch to other language, and add in the place holder attributes 
[image]

So the component varies renders the right text as per the language

[image]